# Calling startService generates a NULL pointer exception

Tags: android, exception, android-intent

I am calling startService(intent) from a client to the service. This call creates an exception:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent("com.L.LService");
final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.L","com.L.LService");
intent.setComponent(cn);
intent.putExtra("intID", "appR");
intent.putExtra("aid", AppID);

try {
  startService(intent);

} catch (Exception e) {

  e.printStacktrace();
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please format your post and provide the full stack trace (which line throws exception?).

Comment: 03-25 07:05:27.156: D/AccountManagerService(59): bind attempt failed for Session: expectLaunch false, connected false, stats (0/0/0), lifetime 0.005, getAccountsByTypeAndFeatures, legacy_google

Comment: 03-25 07:05:27.185: W/EGS:LoginHelper(337): Authentication error: android.accounts.AuthenticatorException: bind failure

Comment: Please put the StackTrace into your question. Please prefix every log line with 4 spaces.

Comment: @Simon the Log lines in your comments seem to be unrelated to the problem.